# Getting the pause/abrupt end time of a playing html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, html5-video

I have a playlist of videos in html. What i want to do is get the time spent by user on each video. So I am on video one and as soon as it starts you click on video two.

So now how to detect the end time (the last position) of video one.

MY THOUGHT

I was actually thinking of making an interval (may be one second ) that notes the currentTime of the playing video, then on video switch before the new video loads, maybe through loadstart method or loadeddata method store the currenttime value to a variable, sent it to database.

So Is this a good way or are there better ways?

Another question which event fires the moment the video acquires the source I mean the first fired event? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the current time when a video is paused/abrupt and calculate the total time as per your requirement.

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime
```

Comment: I know that. I wanted to know if the way I mentioned for getting the time spent on previously viewed video, even though it might be fraction of a second is the right way or not. Plus which method should I use loadStart or loadedData?